# Console column output in python3

Tags: python-3.x, console-application

I am trying to create to create a column output for a few lists that differ in lengths, e.g:

```
list1 = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'goodbye']
list2 = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
list3 = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'hello']
```

desired output:

```
hello    hello   hello
hello    hello   hello
hello    hello   hello
hello            hello
hello
goodbye
```

The individual lists can be quite long, and the lists are linked in a way as we are doing matching of items in the lists and printing matches etc. Hence the need to do it in column format.

I've worked out how to do everything else, apart from printing the desired output.

I have played around with zip, but from my limited experience it does not seem to like lists of different lengths, but I could be doing it all wrong of course. ;-)

Basically I'm  stuck. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, zip only pairs items up to the shortest iterator. What you are looking for is

```
itertools.zip_longest
```

That would pair elements from different iterators and use a fillvalue for when the iterators fall short.

For instance:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

for elems in zip_longest(list1, list2, list3):
    for e in elems:
       print(e or '\t', end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That's certainly the function I am looking for. However I can't seem to get it to print in column format. Your code above works in a way, but it prints each item on a separate line. If I use print('%s %s' % (elems)) after the first for loop that will print the lists in a column, but it will not put a space between the values and  prints 'none' for the blanks. Really I need to combine both methods but I do not have enough knowledge to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: each item on a separate line? print(e, end=" ") should not insert a newline; these would be inserted by the print() at the end of each row —or pairing of elements. The string representation of None —the default fill value for zip_longest— is "None", so you should avoid checking it. I've updated the code to do so.

Comment: edit with your new code and we might figure out what's going on :)

Comment: Gah! I'm so sorry, your original code works fine! The IDE I'm using had me jumping through hoops to solve errors in my code that turn out not to be errors at all, and in my frustration to clear them I'd '#' out code and generally mangled your function in error. Your revised code is more compact so I will give that a whirl later. :-) All that's left for me to work out now is how to make the columns line up nicely, which should give me something to think about over the next couple of days. ;-) Though I've got an idea on how to solve that. Thanks very much for your help on this.

Comment: To have the columns line up, the most easy way is to have a fixed number of chars per column. You can control that at printing time easily: "{:8}".format("hello") would print "hello   ". Have a look at http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: please do mark the question as answered or come back if you need further help! :)